# How to add microdata in website created using Google Sites

Tags: google-classic-sites, html5

Website freely created in Google Sites is not allowing me to add microdata in it. In HTML editor view, I edited and added `itemscope`, `itemtype` and `itemprop`. But once I saved and opened again the HTML editor, those disappeared. Why isn’t Google Sites editor allowing me to add micro data?

Comment: As it stands, your question should be directed to Google as a feature request. If you think there is a way to add microdata, but you can't find out how to do it, you should rephrase your question accordingly.

Comment: modified the title

Answer (score 1):

### Google Caja

The HTML you're adding is sanitized by the Google Caja Compiler. It will check the embedded code for malicious code, and remove the parts that don't fit.

### References

- [Google Caja Playground](https://code.google.com/p/google-caja/wiki/CajaPlayground)
- [Landing site Google Caja](https://code.google.com/p/google-caja/)
- [Google Sites HTML box](https://support.google.com/sites/answer/2500646?hl=en)

Comment: is there any way to add microdata to google sites ?

Comment: @rajaashok To be honest, I don't even know what microdata is. But since it belongs to HTML5, it will probably be sanitized by the Caja compiler, unless it's being released as safe.